# How to trigger actions between applications

Tags: android, ios, function

I'm here to get some information about an idea in my head. I have two applications (running both on iOS and android) with similar functionalities. The first is developed by me, the second is a famous app used to add votes for students.

Now my app has the same feature, but my question is:

Is it possible to write a function or whatever can help me, to make possible that when I add a vote on my app, It also triggers a specific action (in this case, the "add a vote" action) in the second one (the one not developed by me)? I'm not asking you the specific process (because I should give you major details about the two apps), but I want to know:

1) Is it possible?

2) What language, programs, etc. should I use to do that?

3) Maybe links to video or articles that explain how to archive similar objectives

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge, it is not possible to invoke an action from your app to another app which you don't own.

One way which I can possibly think is, if there is a web API exposed from the other application then you may be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: I think there is. I should increase my knowledge about this. Thanks!

Comment: you will have to check if there is. If there isn't there is no way in which you can open some other aaplication.

Comment: @FabrizioCacciapuoti unfortunately no

Comment: And if this second app has also a website? Can I at least open the page to add a vote, login with credentials that the user add in my app and then let him add a vote also on the wibsite? I heard about the http request but I'm not sure they are useful in this case

Comment: I am not sure about the website's flow or if the website will allow registration from outside. Most likely when you will open the vote page in website it will redirect the user to the login page. Also, if there is a way wherein you can register user on website through your app data then also you shouldn't do it without user's consent. User has agreed to share his/her personal data with your application and not authorised you to share their data with someone else.